# Recommended Modeling in a graph database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new in the world of graph databases and wonder about the recommended modeling options for the following classical scenario of Product Buyer-Seller relationship:

- Steve bought iPhone 6 Plus from Amazon

  CREATE (Steve:Person {name: "Steve"})-[b1:BOUGHT]->(iPhone:Product {name: "iPhone 6 Plus"})<-[s1:SELLS]-(Amazon:Company {name: "Amazon"})
- Michael then also bought iPhone 6 Plus, but from eBay

  CREATE (Michael:Person {name: "Michael"})-[b2:BOUGHT]->(iPhone)<-[s2:SELLS]-(eBay:Company {name: "eBay"})

So, Amazon and eBay both sell iPhone 6 Plus and Steve and Michael both bought it.

[**CLICK TO VIEW ILLUSTRATED MODEL WITH THE PRODUCT NODE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jBO0.png)

**Problem:** *There is a concern in this merged modeling in such it is not clear from which company Steve or Michael bought iPhone 6 Plus since the node "iPhone 6 Plus" is shared*.


The modeling could be simplified in such:

```
CREATE (Steve:Person {name: "Steve"})-[b1:BOUGHT_FROM {product: "iPhone 6 Plus"}]->(Amazon:Company {name: "Amazon"})
CREATE (Michael:Person {name: "Michael"})-[b2:BOUGHT_FROM {product: "iPhone 6 Plus"}]->(eBay:Company {name: "eBay"})
```

[**CLICK TO VIEW ILLUSTRATED MODEL WITHOUT THE PRODUCT NODE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsswd.png)

Resulting in loosing the "iPhone 6 Plus" node and replacing it with the approach where the details would be embedded in the relationship properties itself, but allowing at the same a direct relationship between Steve and Amazon.

**is there a way to maintain a clear information in such Steve bought iPhone from Amazon and Michael bought also iPhone from eBay and keeping a node of iPhone at the same time?**

Answer (score 0):

As one simple option, you can add a `Purchase` node that is related to a selling `Company` and one or more `Products` bought from that company.

*The following illustrates the data model, not any Cypher clauses.*

- Steve bought iPhone 6 Plus from Amazon

  ```
  (:Person {name: "Steve"})-[:BOUGHT]->(p:Purchase {id:987, total: 655.99, tax: 56.00})
  (p)-[:PRODUCT {price: 599.99}]->(iPhone:Product {name: "iPhone 6 Plus"})
  (p)-[:SELLER]->(:Company {name: "Amazon"})
  ```
- Michael then also bought iPhone 6 Plus, but from eBay

  ```
  (:Person {name: "Michael"})-[:BOUGHT]->(p:Purchase {id:456, total: 599.99, tax: 0.00}})
  (p)-[:PRODUCT {price: 599.99}]->(iPhone:Product {name: "iPhone 6 Plus"})
  (p)-[:SELLER]->(:Company {name: "eBay"})
  ```

An actual query to make the purchase for `Steve` might look like this:

```
MERGE (person:Person {name: "Steve"})
MERGE (prod:Product {name: "iPhone 6 Plus"})
MERGE (co:Company {name: "Amazon"})
CREATE
  (person)-[:BOUGHT]->(p:Purchase {id:987, total: 655.99, tax: 56.00}),
  (p)-[:PRODUCT {price: 599.99}]->(prod),
  (p)-[:SELLER]->(co);
```

Comment: The bottleneck in this model is that it can't show that Amazon sells the product iPhone in general unless it is LITERALLY bought by Steve

Comment: That is not a problem, since you can still have a SELLS relationship from Amazon (and eBay) to the same iPhone product. But my answer also may not represent the actual model you want to use, since you have to consider all your use cases.